# Loading Adafruit_DHT from Jython

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, python-import

I'm having trouble importing a library called Adafruit_DHT while using the Jython interpreter. Here is what I'm doing:

- Downloaded the Adafruit_DHT Library, put in on my Raspberry Pi 2, installed it with "sudo python setup.py install". When scrips using this library are executed through the normal interpreter, everything's fine.
- Run my java program, which starts a Jython interpreter
- First error: Adafruit_DHT module isn't found when using "import Adafruit_DHT"
- Solved by adding a lot of paths to sys.path
- Next error: "Exception ... File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.1.0-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafrut_DHT/common.py", line 59, in get_platform
  RuntimeError: Unknown platform." Don't really get it. Apparently the library doesnt work properly when called through Jython.
- Solved by nearly deleting all of "get_platform" function in common.py and replacing it by hardcoding Raspberry_Pi_2 as the used platform.
- Next problem: "File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_DHT-1.1.0-py2.7-linux-armv7l.egg/Adafrut_DHT/Raspberry_Pi_2_Driver.py", line 6, in bootstrap
  ImportError: No module named Adafruit_DHT.Raspberry_Pi_2_Driver": Apparently the library itself makes use of modules. And those can't be loaded through Jython

I simply don't get what I should do to properly load and use an installed, rather complex, module like Adafruit_DHT through Jython. I mean, it works fine through the normal python interpreter, so there is no real reason why it shouldn't work through Jython.

Comment: Don't try install a library manualy ! Wrong `Python version`, `Wrong path name`..... Remove all `Adafruit_DHT` and install a clear one. Check `jython` used which python version ? Some module not support all python version(required separate installations).

Comment: @dsgdfg Both the version of Jython and the version of the library are the same though... And also, I don't know what you mean by not installing manually? I installed it by using the "setup.py" shipped with the library, is there another way?

Comment: Friend, `Python3.X.exe  setup.py  install` not equal to `Python2.X.exe  setup.py  install`. Jython used which version of python (is important)?

Comment: @dsgdfg My Jython version is 2.7, and I only have python 2.7 installed on my RPi. So there should be no version clash, right?

Comment: Source (`.so or .c` etc) always include a library. You maybe change file permission on define manual path direction. Some hardware module need root permission on installing or using. Your library not successfully installed! Clear  previous installation and re install. Don't define any one path directions.And put here your trace back !